# How to clone a Visual Studio 2019 Solution Without Rename, Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, clone

How do I clone a Visual Studio 2019 Solution? I don't need to rename it. The clone simply needs to go into a different folder, or could even go onto a different disk.

This question has been asked and answered many times, but the solutions don't seem to work for my use case. The simplest solution seems to be to Copy and Paste the Solution folder. But when I try to open the clone with Visual Studio, I get an error code 0x800004005. I have verified that 100% of the files in all the folders and subfolders of the clone are binary identical to the original prior to opening the clone. The original solution still opens fine after making the clone. If I dismiss the error code window, the clone looks fine and seems to behave fine. If I close, Visual Studio and reopen the clone, it seems to open fine the second time without generating the error code. I'm wondering if the clone is safe to use at that point.

A worrisome aspect of this simple cloning process is that there are numerous instances of files in the solution that store the names of other files in the solution, and the names are stored with absolute file paths all the way back to the drive letter C:\   So the simple copy and paste clone has lots of pointers to files that are in the original solution. This seems very wrong. After getting and dismissing the 0x800004005 error code, many but not all of the file paths within files in the clone now point to files in the clone. But some file paths in the clone still point to the original. I would be happier if they all pointed to the clone, and if the error code 0x800004005 never occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Copy and Paste of the existing Solution folder seems to be complete and correct answer for making a clone of the existing solution when a project does not need to be renamed. This is an answer which has been given before, but I ran into some problems and concerns with using the answer. Some comments are therefore in order.

All the absolute file paths I found in files in the solution were in the .suo file, in .log files, and in .tlog files. These are all temporary files that can safely be deleted. They will be rebuilt or rewritten as needed, and they do not affect the Build>Build Solution process. Also, a Build>Clean Solution will delete the .log and .tlog files in any case.

The file paths used during a Build>Build Solution are all relative file paths and are stored in the .vcxproj files. That is why simply doing a Copy and Paste of the Solution folder will "just work" to make a clone.

I can't explain why I encountered the error code 0x800004005 when I opened the cloned solution with Visual Studio. But it seems to be the case that the error code can be safely dismissed and ignored. It is definitely the case that it can avoided by doing a Build>Clean Solution in the existing solution prior to doing the Copy and Paste of the existing Solution folder to make a clone. I therefore recommend doing a Build>Clean Solution in the existing solution prior to making the clone. I also recommend deleting the .suo file in the existing solution prior to making  the clone. That way, none of the traces of the existing Solution folder are propagated anywhere into the clone.